# Change structure of existing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I want to convert an array into another structure. Here is the original array.

```
[{"level1_label":"Branch 1","data":[{"count":"3","level2_label":"2021-11-11"}]},{"level1_label":"branch 2","data":[{"count":"1","level2_label":"2021-11-25"}]}]
```

I want to convert this array into

```
[
    ['Branch 1', '3', 2021 - 11 - 11],
    ['branch 2', '1', 2021 - 11 - 25]
];
```

Comment: We're not a code-writing service. Please show what you've tried and where you're having problems.

Comment: Have you looked into how to extract values from objects? Once you can do that you can iterate through the original array which is an array of objects - each containing the info you need for an item in the new array.

Comment: Itried with this  const data =[{"level1_label":"Branch 1","data":[{"count":"3","level2_label":"2021-11-11"}]},{"level1_label":"branch 2","data":[{"count":"1","level2_label":"2021-11-25"}]}] const newArray=Object.keys(data).map((key) => Object.keys(data[key]).map(obj => [[data[key][obj], (data.data?.map(it => it.count))]])); But its result is ['Branch 1', undefined]

Comment: Please include what you tried in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `map` I would suggest just iterating:

```js
const data = [{
  "level1_label": "Branch 1",
  "data": [{
    "count": "3",
    "level2_label": "2021-11-11"
  }]
}, {
  "level1_label": "branch 2",
  "data": [{
    "count": "1",
    "level2_label": "2021-11-25"
  }]
}];

const result = [];
data.forEach(l1 => {
  const lev2Arr = [l1.level1_label];
  l1.data.forEach(l2 => {
    lev2Arr.push(l2.count);
    lev2Arr.push(l2.level2_label);
  });
  result.push(lev2Arr);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. when using this iteration method I got the result as expected

Comment: Ok good, please mark above as answer